# Force itemizing in a new line

Tags: theorems, itemize

Is there an easy way (*without editing the theorem environment*) to force 'itemizing' start from a new line inside the remark environment ? I tried `\par` command but nothing seems to happen. I am sure there must be an easy way for this, but I cannot figure it out!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{rem}
\par

\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2 
\end{itemize}

\end{rem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem title is set at the start of the next paragraph via `\everypar`. Therefore, there should be a paragraph *before* the `itemize` environment. This can be achieved with `\mbox{}` or `\leavevmode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{rem}\leavevmode                 

\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{rem}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]